# How do you compute the mean of integers entered by the user that are evenly divisible by a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So far.. I have coded this:

```
While True:
    div_5 = []
    x = float(input("Please input an integer(negative if you want to stop: "))
    x = int(x)
    length = len(div_5)
    total_sum = sum(div_5)
    average = total_sum/length
    if x % 5:
        div_5.append(x)
    if x < 0:
        break
print(average)
```

When I run the code, It says that line 7 has a ZeroDivisionError. What am I doing wrong? I am adding x if it is divisible by 5 to the list, why is saying this? 
Any tips will be helpful for I am new to python.

This is what I need to do

[image]

I have been working on this for a week, hours at a time. I can't seem to get it correct.

Comment: `div-5` and `div_5` are two different things. Be careful!

Comment: Surely you will get the `ZeroDivisionError ` because `total_sum` is the sum of elements of `div_5` which is an empty list intially.

Comment: On the first iteration, you divide by 0 because `len([])` is 0.

Comment: @tadman That was an error! Didn't mean to have div-5! Thanks for pointing that out. Code is still not working. ):

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM How do I get it to take the sum of the list after I add the integers in on line 9?

Comment: Collect all the numbers first and _then_ compute the average... unless the list is empty. The way you're doing it, the list will only ever contain at most one number.

Comment: Presumably you need to test if the number is negative to break out of the loop first, not second. Negative values can produce results with `%`.

Comment: @Blurp How do i do that?

Comment: You're creating a new list on each iteration, so create the list _before_ the loop, collect all the numbers divisible by 5 into the list, break when a negative number is entered, then compute the average _after_ the loop.

Comment: **1** You need to create the `div_5` list _before_ the start of the `while` loop. **2** You're supposed to read integer input, so use `x = int(input("Please input an integer(negative if you want to stop: "))`. **3** Text if `x` is negative immediately after you read it. **4** Don't compute the average until you break out of the loop, and don't compute it if there's no data in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nums = []
while True:
    x = int(input("Please input an integer(negative if you want to stop: "))

    if x < 0:
        div_5 = [x for x in nums if x % 5 == 0]
        try:
            print(sum(div_5)/float(len(div_5)))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print("No number divisible by 5")
        break

    nums.append(x)
```

In fact, you don't need to keep numbers that aren't divisible by 5.  Here is a way with a running average that ignores zeros.

```
count = 0.
average = 0.
while True:
    x = int(input("Please input a positive integer(negative if you want to stop: "))

    if x < 0:
        print(average)
        break
    if x % 5 == 0 and x != 0:
        count += 1
        average = average * (count - 1)/count + (1./count) * x
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If you don't mind, could you explain why you put "except ZeroDivisionError:"  What does it do?

Comment: It catches the exception you would otherwise get when you divide by zero, which will occur when the div_5 list has no values in it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I plan on taking this and breaking it down line at a time to really understand it. Thank you for making things clear for me. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can take hint from this code , but since this seems a school homework so i suggest you should try yourself if you want to improve your coding.

```
user_input=[]
while True:

    x = int(input("Please input an integer(negative if you want to stop: "))
    if x>0:
        user_input.append(x)
    else:
        break

div_5=[item for item in user_input if item%5==0]
print('The mean is {}'.format(sum(div_5)/len(div_5)))
```

output:

```
Please input an integer(negative if you want to stop: 1
Please input an integer(negative if you want to stop: 2
Please input an integer(negative if you want to stop: 3
Please input an integer(negative if you want to stop: 4
Please input an integer(negative if you want to stop: 5
Please input an integer(negative if you want to stop: 6
Please input an integer(negative if you want to stop: 7
Please input an integer(negative if you want to stop: 8
Please input an integer(negative if you want to stop: 9
Please input an integer(negative if you want to stop: 15
Please input an integer(negative if you want to stop: -12
The mean is 10.0
```

Comment: It is just some practice for my CSC class! I have been trying over and over for hours each day to try and figure it out myself and I just couldn't! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Madison sure if you face issue with last one line expression which is list comprehension , i can explain it.

Comment: Not a problem. BTW, the OP is using Python 3, so the `float` conversion is unnecessary. FWIW, you can get Python 3 behaviour with `/` division in Python 2.2+ by doing `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: sure i removed the float stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments:

1. You need to create the `div_5` list before the start of the `while` loop.
2. You're supposed to read integer input, so that `float` call is useless.
3. Test if `x` is negative immediately after you read it.
4. Don't compute the average until you break out of the loop, and don't compute it if there's no data in the list.

Also, your test for divisibility is backwards: `x % 5` is zero if `x` is divisible by 5, and zero is considered False.

Here's a repaired version of your code.

```
div_5 = []
while True:
    x = int(input("Please input an integer (negative if you want to stop): "))
    if x < 0:
        break
    if x % 5 == 0:
        div_5.append(x)

if div_5:
    average = sum(div_5) / len(div_5)
else:
    average = 0
print(average)
```

**Demo**

```
Please input an integer (negative if you want to stop): 1
Please input an integer (negative if you want to stop): 5
Please input an integer (negative if you want to stop): 6
Please input an integer (negative if you want to stop): 10
Please input an integer (negative if you want to stop): -4
7.5
```

When we break out of the main loop the test `if div_5` test if there are any numbers in the `div_5` list and only performs the division if there are. If there are no numbers in the list, then the average is zero.